# ubuntu crontab -e "/usr/bin/sensible-editor" killed; signal 9 (no core dumped)

Tags: ubuntu, cron

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 11.04 (GNU/Linux 2.6.32-042stab037.1 x86_64)
user@server:~$ crontab -e
no crontab for user - using an empty one

Select an editor.  To change later, run 'select-editor'.
  1. /bin/ed
  2. /bin/nano        <---- easiest
  3. /usr/bin/mcedit
  4. /usr/bin/vim.basic

Choose 1-4 [2]: 2
crontab: "/usr/bin/sensible-editor" killed; signal 9 (no core dumped)
Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM
Error writing /tmp/crontab.qcuMPr/crontab.save: No such file or directory
Buffer not written to /tmp/crontab.qcuMPr/crontab.save: No such file or directory
```

Why is this happening?

https://gist.github.com/1751927

Comment: results for `file /usr/bin/sensible-editor`?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/1751927

Answer (score 4):

/usr/bin/sensible-editor is just a wrapper to help you choose an editor.

What happens when you do this?

```
export EDITOR=nano
crontab -e
```

Does /usr/bin/nano exist?

Comment: When i use `export EDITOR=nano` everything is fine.

Comment: Did `sensible-editor` create a file `~/.selected_editor` ?  That's just a shell script setting an environmental variable SELECTED_EDITOR.

Comment: Yes, file do exists.

Comment: `~$ ls -al | grep '.selected'`
`-rw-r--r-- 1 user user       66 2012-02-06 14:42 .selected_editor`
`~$ cat .selected_editor`
`# Generated by /usr/bin/select-editor`
`SELECTED_EDITOR="/bin/nano"`

Comment: After I execute`export EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim`.And execute `crontab -e`, and it display `crontab: "/usr/bin/vi" exited with status 1`.